# E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I wanted to install bluefish editor but I got this error. This is not the first error I got involving packages. I installed Linux Mint 17 two days ago and every time after a reboot there is some kind of problem with packages. Anyone have an idea?

```
user@username ~ $ sudo apt-get install bluefish
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bluefish-data bluefish-plugins
Suggested packages:
  bluefish-dbg libxml2-utils tidy weblint-perl weblint
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bluefish bluefish-data bluefish-plugins
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2 548 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9 484 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

additional info:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

as well as

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

run with no error

Edits:

`sudo dpkg -C` does nothing

```
user@username ~ $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       161G   14G  140G   9% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1,4M  394M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            2,0G  1,7M  2,0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5       168G   67G  102G  40% /mnt/DATA

user@username ~ $ sudo apt-get -fv install bluefish
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Oct  8 2014 12:36:19
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Standard Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Standard Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file
```

Comment: You sure that's all the output? What's the output of `sudo dpkg -C`? Also `df -h`

Comment: Can you try: `sudo apt-get -fv install bluefish` and post the output?

Comment: `sudo dpkg -C` does nothing

Comment: @Braiam  here's the oitput of`df -h`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6       161G   14G  140G   9% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            2,0G  4,0K  2,0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  1,4M  394M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            2,0G  1,7M  2,0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda5       168G   67G  102G  40% /mnt/DATA

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the output. Nobody can read in comments.

Comment: @ryekayo sudo apt-get -fv install bluefish
apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Oct  8 2014 12:36:19
Supported modules:
*Ver: Standard .deb
*Pkg:  Debian dpkg interface (Priority 30)
 Pkg:  Debian APT solver interface (Priority -1000)
 S.L: 'deb' Standard Debian binary tree
 S.L: 'deb-src' Standard Debian source tree
 Idx: Debian Source Index
 Idx: Debian Package Index
 Idx: Debian Translation Index
 Idx: Debian dpkg status file
 Idx: EDSP scenario file

Comment: @Braiam sorry didn't quite figured out how this works. It's edited now

Comment: Does `bluefish-data` and `bluefish-plugins` give the same result if you try to install them? What about some other package? Also, for `sudo apt-get install bluefish` are you sure that's all the output you get?

Comment: @FaheemMitha trying to install `bluefish-data` and `bluefish-plugins` gives the same error. And yes it's all the output I get

Comment: What about some other package? Can you download the `bluefish-data` binary deb package via `apt-get download` or `aptitude download` or just from a Debian web page and try installing it with `dpkg -i`?

Comment: @FaheemMitha download worked but `dpkg -i bluefish` gave me this error `dpkg: error: reading package info file '/var/lib/dpkg/available': Input/output error`

Comment: “Input/output error” on a disk file is a bad sign: it usually indicates a corrupted filesystem because the hard disk or the RAM is failing. Look for more clues in `/var/log/kern.log` (the kernel logs). Run a [memory test](http://www.memtest.org/) as soon as possible. Be prepared to replace some hardware. If it's a RAM failure, beware that some of your files may already be corrupted.

Comment: @Mathis As Gilles says, that points to a hardware problem. No purely software problem would produce "Input/output error". I'd check hard drives and memory. It is probably one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested (in comments)

> Can you download the `bluefish-data` binary deb package via `apt-get download` or `aptitude download` or just from a Debian web page and try installing it with `dpkg -i`?

The poster replied:

> dpkg -i bluefish
>
> gave me this error
>
> dpkg: error: reading package info file
>      '/var/lib/dpkg/available': Input/output error

This suggests that the problem is almost certainly hardware related. 
"Input/output error" is not a software error.
There is a problem with either the hard disk or the memory.

Comment: Yes it was a disk. Right when I restarted the computer to perform a memtest I wasn't able to boot the disk. Eventually after quite a few attempts I managed to boot from the from the hard drive a save the most valuable data. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mathis fyi, you can accept the answer (if it does answer your question) by clicking the tick mark by the answer.